# How can i simulate MAC Flooding Attack in Cisco Packet Tracer on windows?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Is there anyway to simulate a mac flooding attack without using linux/Ubuntu? 
I have windows and i have to simulate on it.

Is it possible to simulate on Cisco Packet tracer?

Comment: Packet tracer is a limited tool designed to help you practice for the CCNA exams. It does not have advanced features.

Comment: You can use [GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/) instead of packet tracer to have Linux VM alongside Cisco devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  **you can't**.  As the comments indicate, Packet Tracer is a practice tool, not a network simulator.  You can try using something like GNS3, which can run real IOS software as well as Linux VMs.